# API call limit in Salesforce

Tags: c#-4.0, salesforce

Can I get to know or check how many calls have been made to Salesforce in C#?
This will help me in checking Call count limitation to user and update same to him.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [LimitInfoHeader](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_limitinfo.htm) from the Partner API to monitor the current API usage.

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <LimitInfoHeader>
        <limitInfo>
            <current>5</current>
            <limit>5000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
        </limitInfo>
    </LimitInfoHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
```

It is also available in the REST API - [Limit Info Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_api_usage.htm).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 20 May 2013 22:21:46 GMT
Sforce-Limit-Info: api-usage=18/5000
```